# Heroku using django and twisted

Tags: python, django, heroku, websocket, twisted

I want put my working app on Heroku. The application using Django and chat based on Twisted websockets. I don't know it's good approach but I installed twisted via heroku bash, but when i want to run my chatserver.py I have an exception because some Twisted module requires OpenSSL which is not installed on my env.

So simply question, how to install Twisted to work with websocket on Heroku?

**Update**
when I run twistd -n -y chatserver.py:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/application/app.py", line 652, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/application/app.py", line 386, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/application/app.py", line 451, in createOrGetApplication
    application = getApplication(self.config, passphrase)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/application/app.py", line 462, in getApplication
    application = service.loadApplication(filename, style, passphrase)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/application/service.py", line 405, in loadApplication
    application = sob.loadValueFromFile(filename, 'application', passphrase)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/persisted/sob.py", line 210, in loadValueFromFile
    exec fileObj in d, d
  File "chatserver.py", line 37, in <module>
    from twisted.web.websockets import WebSocketsResource, lookupProtocolForFactory
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/web/websockets.py", line 28, in <module>
    from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 40, in <module>
    from OpenSSL.SSL import Error, ZeroReturnError, WantReadError
exceptions.ImportError: No module named OpenSSL.SSL

Failed to load application: No module named OpenSSL.SSL
```

So when I try to install openssl with command: pip install pyopenssl

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_u12732/cryptography/setup.py", line 174, in <module>

    "test": PyTest,

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 260, in __init__

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 285, in fetch_build_eggs

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 631, in resolve

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 871, in best_match

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 883, in obtain

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 335, in fetch_build_egg

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 595, in easy_install

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 625, in install_item

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 822, in install_eggs

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1028, in build_and_install

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1016, in run_setup

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_u12732/cryptography
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 75: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Did you try installing pyOpenSSL?

Comment: Yes there is some errors while installing OpenSSL from heroku bash

Comment: Either you need to overcome those errors or find a way to run your application without TLS support.  I don't think there's enough information here for anyone to be able to provide you with a specific, helpful answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like a pip bug (<https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1501>) is preventing the real error from being reported.